# VBA Userform Command Button to copy row to sheet before editing information

Tags: vba, excel

I have a secondary user-form which can edit cell data based on a double click selection from a list-box.

The user-form has an 'update' button which will execute change in data in the cells based on the input to text boxes and combo boxes.

Everything is working perfectly, however I would like to keep an 'archive' of the data before the row is updated. (Essentially copy the row to 'Archive' sheet4)

I have tried to include the .Selection method however this change my active worksheet and the update information doesn't appear.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
' To write edited info of userform2 to Sheets("Data")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ABnum As Double
    Dim ABrng As Range
    Dim WriteRow As Long

    'error statement
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Make sure we're on the right sheet
Sheets("Data").Select
    With ActiveSheet
' Get the last row used so can set up the search range
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Set the range to search for the AB number
        Set ABrng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
' Get the AB number from what is selected on userform2
    ABnum = txtup1.Value

' Get the row of sheet for this AB number
    WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)

' Make this AB number the active cell
        Cells(WriteRow, 1).Select
' Write in all the editable options
        With ActiveCell
            .Offset(0, 4) = cboup3.Value
            .Offset(0, 5) = cboup4.Value
            .Offset(0, 6) = cboup5.Value
            .Offset(0, 7) = cboup6.Value
            .Offset(0, 8) = Date
            .Offset(0, 12) = txtup9.Value
            .Offset(0, 13) = txtup8.Value

        End With

End With
' Filter the Data
    FilterMe
' Close the form
    Unload Me

    MsgBox ("Enquiry E0" + Me.txtup1.Text + " has been updated")

errHandler:
'Protect all sheets if error occurs
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " just occured."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but here is a best guess. I have only made a stab at where you want one piece of data stored, but if I am on the right lines then the code can be amended to cover the others. If you can clarify the destination Archive sheet that would help.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
' To write edited info of userform2 to Sheets("Data")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ABnum As Double
Dim ABrng As Range
Dim WriteRow As Long

'error statement
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Make sure we're on the right sheet
With Sheets("Data")
' Get the last row used so can set up the search range
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' Set the range to search for the AB number
    Set ABrng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
' Get the AB number from what is selected on userform2
    ABnum = txtup1.Value
' Get the row of sheet for this AB number
    WriteRow = Application.Match(ABnum, ABrng, 0)
' Make this AB number the active cell
    With .Cells(WriteRow, 1)
' Write in all the editable options
    Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(, 14).Value = .Resize(, 14).Value
        .Offset(0, 4) = cboup3.Value
        .Offset(0, 5) = cboup4.Value
        .Offset(0, 6) = cboup5.Value
        .Offset(0, 7) = cboup6.Value
        .Offset(0, 8) = Date
        .Offset(0, 12) = txtup9.Value
        .Offset(0, 13) = txtup8.Value
    End With
End With
' Filter the Data
FilterMe
' Close the form
Unload Me

MsgBox ("Enquiry E0" + Me.txtup1.Text + " has been updated")

errHandler:
'Protect all sheets if error occurs
'Protect_All
'show error information in a messagebox
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " just occured."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would like the found row from the `ABnum = txtup1.Value` to be copied to sheet 4 (Archive) before editing the data in 'data' sheet, there are 14 columns to copy, starting from A

Comment: Not sure I follow, can you elaborate as to what you mean by the "found row" - which sheet, which cells?

Comment: I was hoping to just do `entire.copy` but that was creating the problem. I think your solution works but i need to copy the information from 14 columns to the data sheet

Comment: OK have amended a line above so try again and let me know how you get on.

Comment: It hasn't copied anything across, Would you like me to send the entire Document?

Comment: Could you try again, I missed something.

Comment: Glad to hear it.